# Parse Nested JSON with MiniJSON (Unity3D)

Tags: json, facebook, unity-game-engine, nested

i'm very **newbie** with **JSON** so i'm having problems with **nested JSON's**. 
I was searching two days without any luck, i saw a lot of examples of how to deserialize a nested JSON but my efforts failed so at last chance i'm here.

The thing **i want to know is how i deserialize nested class with MiniJson**, the JSONString is a facebook one, but i want to know the method for do it.

Here is an **example** of the JSONString i'm trying to deserialize.

```
{"data":
[{"user":{"name":"xxxxxxxxx1","id":"xxxxxxxxxx2"},"score":7,

"application":
{"name":"APPNAME","namespace":"APPNAMESPACE","id":"xxxxxxxxxx3"}}]}
```

Thanks in advance...

I tried with a lot of things this one is the last attempt i did, not a lot good but i was trying like a crazy to do it:

```
object dataObject;
            object scoreObject;
            var dict = Json.Deserialize(response.Text) as Dictionary<string,object>;
            Debug.Log(response.Text);


            var scores = new List<object>();
            if(dict.TryGetValue ("data", out scoreObject)) {
                Debug.Log("Hi");
                scores = (string)(((Dictionary<string, object>)scoreObject) ["score"]);
                if(scores.Count > 0) {
                    var scoreDict = ((Dictionary<string,object>)(scores[0]));
                    var score = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    score["score"] = (string)scoreDict["score"];
                    Debug.Log((string)scoreDict["score"]);
                }
            }
```

PD: Sorry if my question is very noob or if i have a lot of negatives but it's really my last chance to understand something, thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in the fact that **data** contains an array and not an object, you need to get the first element of the **data** array and then get the value of score.

Something like this:

```
var dict = Json.Deserialize(response.Text) as Dictionary<string,object>;

List<object> scores = dict["data"] as List<object>;

Dictionary<string,object> scoreData = scores[0] as Dictionary<string,object>;

object score = scoreData["score"];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Hades, now i can understand it more well, i though that data wasn't an array.

I can't upvote your answer because i don't have reputation but thanks a lot, really you saved my day.

Comment: Glad I could help, in the future you could use a pretty print tool for JSON to see the JSON better, I'm using this one http://jsonprettyprint.com/ . It's really simple, but it gets the job done.