# Retrieve player score with JSON

Tags: json, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am trying to retrieve a player score using facebook API in Unity. This is the code that I am using:

```
if (FB.IsLoggedIn) {
    FB.API("/me/scores", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, scoreRetrieved);
}

public void scoreRetrieved(FBResult result) {
    var dict = Json.Deserialize(result.Text) as Dictionary<string,object>;
    print (dict["score"]);
}
```

and this is the result of FBResult result.text :

```
{"data":[{"user":{"id":"1000015239203","name":"AAA BBB"},"score":30,"application":{"name":"game","id":"2419296161993"}}]}
```

How can I access the score? It's not working for me a have an error because the key doesn't exist!

Comment: Yes, data is the only key that exists in dict

Comment: so how can i access the score value ?

Comment: dict['data'][0]['score']

Comment: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type `object'

Comment: this has been answered here :D I got the same problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739791/parse-nested-json-with-minijson-unity3d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was painfull but i found a solution:

```
public void scoreRetrived(FBResult result){
    var dict = Json.Deserialize(result.Text) as Dictionary<string,object>;
    List<object> data = dict["data"] as List<object>;
    int playerScore = int.Parse(((Dictionary<string, object>)data.ToArray()[0])["score"].ToString());
}
```

wow finally !!

Answer (score 0):

If you expand the format of your JSON array to be more human readable, it will look like:

```
{
    "data":[
        {
            "user": {
                "id":   "1000015239203",
                "name": "AAA BBB"
            },
            "score": 30,
            "application": {
                "name": "game",
                "id":   "2419296161993"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Therefore, to access the Score, you need

```
dict['data']['score']
```

or possibly:

```
dict.data.score
```

depending on the language.