# I want Parse Json using MiniJson and store it in a list for manipulation

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, facebook-c#-sdk

```
    {
    "players": [
    {
    "wins": 8,
    "losses": 1,
    "score": 264.5,
    "pro": false,
    "name": "albert"
    },
    {
    "wins": 7,
    "losses": 1,
    "score": 214.5,
    "pro": false,
    "name": "mike"
    }
```

I want to parse it and I have tried as below:

```
    Dictionary<string,object> data=MiniJSON.Json.Deserialize(json) as Dictionary<string,object>;
    List<object> list=(List<object>)(data["Person"]);
    //data["players"] as List<object>
    foreach(var item in data)
    {
     // data as Dictionary<string,object>
    Dictionary<string,object> dict=(Dictionary<string,object>)(data);
    }
```

I Tried But I don't know whether It is coorect or not and I Have not able to proceed further please 
spare a minute to help me

Comment: You're using unity, correct?  Then maybe see [Serialize and Deserialize Json and Json Array in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36239705/3744182).  [Parse Nested JSON with MiniJSON (Unity3D)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22739791) might help also.  But you wrote, *I Tried But I don't know whether It is coorect or not and I Have not able to proceed further* -- then what problem did you encounter?  Was an exception thrown?

Comment: S i am using unity but the above article i already viewed i dint get any idea from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Your Json is not valid:
you can use this [site](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate json. You should add ']' and '}'. So you json should look like:

```
{
    "players": 
    [
        {
            "wins": 8,
            "losses": 1,
            "score": 264.5,
            "pro": false,
            "name": "albert"
        },
        {
            "wins": 7,
            "losses": 1,
            "score": 214.5,
            "pro": false,
            "name": "mike"
        }
    ]
}
```

2) You can use Unity JsonUtility.
Create class Player

```
[Serializable]
public class Player
{
    int wins;
    int losses;
    int score;
    bool pro;
    string name;
}
```

Then create player container

```
public class PlayerContainer
{
    List<Player> players = new List<Player>();
}
```

Now you can use JsonUtility to serialize/deserialize your data

```
public class PlayersController
{
    private void Start()
    {
        string json = "your json";
        var players = JsonUtility.FromJson<PlayerContainer>(json);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but I Have to use Minijson only if u can tell me that it is more useful Anyway Thanks for sparing a moment to Help Me

Comment: just use this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739791/parse-nested-json-with-minijson-unity3d and fix your json text

Comment: Sir It Would be helpful if u answer as u answered like above clearly please

Comment: string json = "your json";
var dict = Json.Deserialize(json  as Dictionary<string,object>;
List<object> players= dict["players"] as List<object>;

Comment: Is that enough sir for deserialization and how to add it to list?